# Java - file format as a folder

Tags: java, android, format, directory

I'm developing a java library for use on Android devices and java desktop applications.
In this library, I want to pack several files in one file with a custom extension.
The only need I have at that extension is to add and delete files (text and images).

What would be the simplest way to implement this?

I'm trying with tar and zip. But in these formats I can not delete entries easily.
I know ZipFileSystem, but it depends on nio and Android does not have full support.

I want a solution that is purely java, and can run on android and java desktop applications.

I want a format that works as a folder.

Thank you.
Excuse my English.

Comment: `I want to generate files with a custom extension. `. No. You want to pack several files in one file. That the resulting file has a custom extension is irrelevant. Please rephrase your post.

Comment: is there any reason you can't just make a folder named something unique instead of inventing a file format? that seems like overkill

Comment: @nhouser9 A folder is not a file. I need for the user is a file. So you can share, or give double click to open the application.